# What were the most influential concepts in Hume's 'Treatise on Human Nature'?

Tags: hume

Is there thought within this work that is considered the most revelatory and influential of all ideas presented, or is it just thought of as a generally well written work? If it does contain specific ideas that have been particularly important in the history of philosophy, what are they?

Comment: Hume's account of [causation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hume/#Cau).